# Linux symlinks to directories

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, pwd

I created a symlink in my home folder to another directory:

```
$ pwd
/home/user1
$ ln -s /usr/local/dir/ shortcut
$ ls -l
................................... shortcut -> /usr/local/dir/
$ cd shortcut
$ pwd
/home/user1/shortcut
```

I do end up in that dir so I can see all the files in there but the `pwd` is confusing and could cause issues. Is there a better way to this so that it acts a shortcut and actually shows `/usr/local/dir` when I go into `cd shortcut` instead of showing the new path?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [pwd without symlinks](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/6800/80216) and [Strange difference between pwd and /bin/pwd](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/145479/80216).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has already been answered on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](//unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @G-Man, is this a case of the question being answered elsewhere on a similar question, or the OP cross-posting the same question and getting an answer on another site?  The links in the first comment are to older questions.  The link in the close comment is to the site rather than a specific post and the OP isn't a user there.  Just the existence of an answer on another site wouldn't make it off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `cd` and `pwd` have flags to use the physical directory structure.

## cd

```bash
$ cd --help
...
  -P   use the physical directory structure without following
       symbolic links: resolve symbolic links in DIR before
       processing instances of `..'
...
```

e.g

```
$ cd /var/tmp 
$ ln -s /home/user test 
$ cd -P test
$ pwd
/home/user
```

Above, we use `cd -P` to use the physical directory structure, so now `pwd` gives us the physical path.

## pwd

```
$ pwd
...
  -P    print the physical directory, without any symbolic links
...
```

e.g

```
$ cd /var/tmp
$ ln -s /home/user test 
$ cd test
$ pwd
/var/tmp/test
$ pwd -P
/home/user
```

Above, we `cd`'d into the directory as normal, so `pwd` gives the symbolic path. Using `pwd -P` will give the physical path.

## Set globally in bash

If you are using `bash` you can tell it to ignore symbolic links entirely and just use the physical directory structure by running `set -P` (shorthand for `set -o physical`, see the `bash man page). This is likely possible with other shells too.

Comment: This resets to default on every logout. So while logged in, running the command gives the desired results but logging out and back resets it to default. Is there a way to make it remember the "set -P"?

Comment: Ah bad wording on my part, that only persists per shell. You can set this in `~/.bashrc`, this will be loaded for every interactive shell, then to make sure it's loaded for ssh etc... you can place it in `~/.bash_profile` or run `source ~/.bashrc` from `~/.bash_profile` - it may already be sourced, depending on the distro.

Answer (score 0):

Use $CDPATH

```
$ CDPATH=/usr/local
$ cd dir
$ pwd
/usr/local/dir
```

Comment: ISTM that that is more of a work-around than a real answer, and might be better as a comment.

Comment: I agree. The answer from wayofthepie above is spot on and what I was hoping for. Easy, global, built-in. Not a negative aspect to it.